# XAMPP error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly when trying to start Apache

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache, xampp, localhost

i just installed XAMPP and when i try to start apache and mySQL i got this error:

```
16:50:25  [Apache]     Status change detected: running
16:50:26  [Apache]     Status change detected: stopped
16:50:26  [Apache]     Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
16:50:26  [Apache]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
16:50:26  [Apache]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
16:50:26  [Apache]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
16:50:26  [Apache]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
16:50:26  [Apache]     If you need more help, copy and post this
16:50:26  [Apache]     entire log window on the forums
```

I tried reading several forums/youtube videos that suggests to change port 80 to 8080 and 443 to 4433 followed their instructions and it still doesn't work for me. Does it have to do with the way I installed that's why i get the error? or there's just a blocked port? or something. Help me on my midterms pls :(

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing proper logs. But did you change any VHOST settings? I've seen this error when an improper directory is set for one of my vhosts.

Comment: Also, if you go to the XAMPP control panel and click `Netstat` you can see if the ports you are using are already in use.